# Data which is succesfully added in database, doesnt show in database

Tags: php, mysql

im adding data in databese with php and received "succesful" but when i look into the database the data which is i have just added doesnt show. Here my codes

```
<?php
require ('db.php');

@$name    =   $_POST['name'];
@$surname =   $_POST['surname'];
@$number  =   $_POST['number'];
@$mail    =   $_POST['mail'];
@$note    =   $_POST['note'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO customersinfo (name,surname,number,email,notes) VALUES ($name,$surname,$number,$mail,$note)";

$con->query($sql);
if ($sql)
{
echo "Succesful";
}

else
{
echo "error";
}
?>
```

this is also my db.php codes ;

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","customers");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf(" Connection error :(  %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}
?>
```

i also have one more question. When i try to add data in databese with mysqli_query() function, it doesnt work. for example;

```
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO customersinfo (name,surname,number,email,notes) VALUES($name,$surname,$number,$email,$note)");
```

because of this , i had to use this code,its working now but i have no idea why mysqli_query() function is doesnt work

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO customersinfo (name,surname,number,email,notes) VALUES ($name,$surname,$number,$mail,$note)";

$con->query($sql);
```

if you help me it would be great, thank you.

Comment: change `VALUES($name,$surname,$number,$email,$note)` to `VALUES('$name','$surname','$number','$email','$note')`

Comment: A quick side note, please dont use `@` to suppress errors, solve them instead, in your case it would only need a simple `isset` (or `empty`) check for the variables

Comment: missing quotes in values!! better use bind and prepare statement

Comment: Check this link http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp. You are  not checking whether data is inserted or not. Your condition is wrong . Change the condition. if($con->query($sql)){

echo "Succesful";
}else{

}

Comment: Thank you for your answers , when i do not use @ i receive Undefined variable warning. i ' ll try with bind and prepare , thank you for link i ' ll check

Answer (score 0):

**Put single quote(') in values like this**

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO customersinfo (name,surname,number,email,notes) VALUES ('$name','$surname','$number','$mail','$note')";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are checking just `$sql` variable which doesn't provide sql resul, it's just a query.

Try

```
$result = $con->query($sql);
if($result)
{
  echo "Succesful";
}else{
  echo "error";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

More proper way:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `customersinfo`
(`name`,`surname`,`number`,`email`,`notes`) VALUES
('{$name}','{$surname}','{$number}','{$mail}','{$note}')";

$result=$con->query($sql);

if (!$result) {
     // Query has failed 
}
```

Comment: i tried but unfortunately it didnt work. also i have tried like 
    $sql = "INSERT INTO customersinfo
(`name`,`surname`,`number`,`email`,`notes`) VALUES
('{$name}','{$surname}','{$number}','{$mail}','{$note}')"; 

i mean table name without ' ' but it didnt work either.

Answer (score 0):

You checked $sql in if condition which is not right because $sql is always true so that u get the result successful but actually value is not getting inserted in database.

take the result in some variable and used that in if condition.
after that you will get what actual error in your code.